# Changing the Windows authentication users allowed to access SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, authentication

This seems like a question that should be common enough, but I can't find anything on it.  Two questions, really:

- How can I determine which account(s) have Windows authentication access to an instance of SQL Server 2008?
- Can I change that set of users without being able to log in to the SQL Server instance?

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sys.server_principals` view contains all the logins with access to the instance. You can filter by type `U` and `G` to get just Windows logins and Windows groups.

You can use the the T-SQL commands `CREATE LOGIN`, `ALTER LOGIN` and `DROP LOGIN` to manage logins without using the GUI. There are similar commands available for database users.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx)
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189751.aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173463.aspx

Comment: I finally managed to get it working with your help - thank you very much!